# Stopping the loop

Tags: java

```
for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
        if (xx2==0){
            f =xx1*(Math.pow(x,p))+xx3;
            derF =   xx1*(p*(Math.pow(x,(p-1)))); 
            get3=x-(f/derF);
            Arr[j+1]=get3;
            String roundXn = df3.format(Arr[j+1]);
            String roundfxprime = df3.format(derF);
            String roundfx = df3.format(f);
            if (Arr[j]==Arr[j+1])
            {
                break;
            } 


            //x=x2;
            System.out.println("\n" + j+"\t" + x +"\t" + roundfx +"\t" +roundfxprime +"\t" +roundXn); 
            //roundXn = Convert.parseInt(
            Double Xn1= Double.parseDouble(roundXn);

            x = Xn1;
```

Code result:

[image: screenshot]

I want the loop to stop at 3rd iteration, but the loop still continues. How do I stop it?

Comment: What is xx2 ? First, read how to ask a question and then I can help

Comment: Maybe `j < 3` in the outer for loop declaration?

Comment: Hi randy and welcome to stackoverflow! Your question seems to be a bit confusing. Surf over to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and check out how to ask a question to get achieve a high chance of getting an answer to your question.

Comment: In the output. The iteration still continues.. Its supposed to stop at 3 iteration.

Comment: @FallAndLearn xx2 is a user input. If he input 0 the condition is executed

Comment: @sics. Sorry about that. Its my first time to ask here..

Comment: 3rd Iteration is only valid for this case right? Other params may result in different count of iterations if I understand correctly. So you'll have to think about what exactly shall be the criteria to break the loop.Is it when Fx == Xn+1 ? If so, then you have to check for that condition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: @fildor the iteration is suppsoed to stop if the Xn+1 has the same result.

Comment: There you go ... `if( x == Xn1 ) break; else x = Xn1;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

`for(int j=0;j<3;j++)`

or add a check in place where you need (maybe before `if (xx2==0){`)

`if(j==2) 
    break;`

You can exit any lopp in java by using `break;`

Comment: Nope... The loop is supposed to stop if Xn+1 has the same value.

Comment: @RandyCorpuz in that case I totally not understand your question. Xn+1 "has the same value" like what?

Comment: Look at the screenshot i attach on my post.

Comment: @RandyCorpuz if(x == Xn1) break;